# Access stored procedure via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I want to access a SQL server stored procedure via python, using sqlalchemy. I want to assign the table queried to a dataframe.

I have created the script in SQL and it returns the correct table, I have tried pasting the full script in as the query string however this returns zero results. I have tried simple "select * from x" queries and these work.

```
python
connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{usr}:{password}@DUMMYDATABASE?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")

query = """USE [DATABASE_REPORTING]
           GO
           EXEC [dbo].[PARKING_ALERT];"""

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

I expect the output to be a data frame with approximately 200,000 rows but instead receive the following error

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000]
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near 'GO'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: USE [DATABASE_REPORTING]
>              GO
>              EXEC [dbo].[PARKING_ALERT];] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL keyword, it's an SSMS/sqlcmd keyword. Get rid of the `GO` and the `USE` statement and connect to the correct database in your connection string.

Comment: @Lamu the above resolves my initial error and it will now run simple stored procedures (select* from), however it is returning no rows for more complicated stored procedures that include the creation of several temp tables but still ultimately returning one table.

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is where my expertise stops; I have no experience with `sqlalchemy`. I remember, from something I worked on several years ago with a PHP project, that the statements (like an `INSERT` within an SP were interpreted as datasets, even though they didn't return one, so the correct "dataset" had to be cycled to. Perhaps `sqlalchemy` works the same way. I have no idea, but i'm sure that someone with familiarity of the technology will have an answer; or have more questions for you.

Comment: (Also, there is no `m` in my alias)